# Any extra configurations for ssr after migrating angular 16 to 17?

Tags: angular, typescript, vercel

I want to use and take the benefits from angular 17 like ssr, I already migrate from angular 16 to 17, install the @angular/ssr, and did the commit and push the changes to vercel and no changes about ssr is taking place, I already search information and not found anithing.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "cli": {
    "cache": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "analytics": false
  },
  "projects": {
    "newAvance": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/newAvance/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/themecss/lib.css",
              "src/assets/css/themecss/so_megamenu.css",
              "src/assets/css/themecss/so-categories.css",
              "src/assets/css/themecss/so-listing-tabs.css",
              "src/assets/css/themecss/animate.css",
              "src/assets/css/themecss/so-super-category.css",
              "src/theme.css",
              "src/assets/css/responsive.css",
              "node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
              
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js",
              "src/assets/js/precios.js",
              "src/assets/js/main.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "4mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "4mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "newAvance:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "newAvance:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "newAvance:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/newAvance/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "newAvance:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "newAvance:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "newAvance:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "newAvance:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "newAvance:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "newAvance:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "newAvance:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "newAvance:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here it is my angular.json file.

Comment: How did you add `@angular/ssr` ? Did you run `ng add @angular/ssr ` ?  Are you using the application builder ?

Comment: Yes, I run ng add @angular/ssr and for build using ng build.

Comment: can you share your  `angular.json` config ?

Comment: I update the post with the angular.json file

Comment: Have you tried running the application builder migration with `ng update @angular/cli —-name use-application-builder`  ?

Comment: I do not apply that command, i already did it, I have a question, what command I use for do the build and to run?

Comment: `ng serve` will start `ssr` for the with `build-angular:application`.  (if you have a server.ts)